# How do you give the resulting set a name when calling Linqpad's .Dump() method on a List<>?

Tags: linq, linqpad

Say I make the following query expression:

```
var clients =  
    (from c in Clients  
     where (c.Age == 20)  
     select new { c.FirstName, c.LastName }  
    ).ToList();
```

Calling clients.Dump() in Linqpad shows the following in the Results Panel:

[image: List<> (5 items)]

Is there a way to rename the set's header, to let's say 'clients', instead of 'List<> (5 items)'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The header indicates the type, so you can't rename it without changing the collection type. Instead, you would normally call .Dump with a heading:

```
clients.Dump ("clients")
```

and then you get the list with a heading of 'clients'.

Comment: For anyone curious, you can see what clients.Dump("Clients") looks like [here](http://i.imgur.com/vQRLXKb.png).